# SQL, subquery if null

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou a fazer uma query, mas não queria que ela retorne NULL.

O que tenho é isto:

```
select ifnull(sum(job_withdraw_qty),0) as total,

 (
   select IFNULL(sum(job_withdraw_qty),0) 
   from job_positions 
   where DATE_FORMAT(job_positions.created_on, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2016-01-01'
   and is_hired = 1
   and jobs.job_origem = 730

 ) as aumento

 from job_positions
 inner join jobs
 on job_positions.job_id = jobs.job_id
 where DATE_FORMAT(job_positions.created_on, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2016-01-01'
 and is_hired = 1
```

Só que ao executar a query:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No campo total está tudo bem mas no aumento não, alguém sabe uma solução?

Comment: o `ifnull` tem que ficar pra fora do parentese: `ifnull(select ...), 0) as aumento`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `ifnull` tem que ficar pra fora do parentese da `subquery`:

```
ifnull((select ...), 0) as aumento
```